# How to add non related table to othe related tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables users, user_bio and books

```
user_tb
id | name  
-------------
 1 | Dan
 2 | Mick
 3 | Jane

user_bio
id | uid | bio
-------------
 1 | 2   | Micks bio
 2 | 3   | Janes bio
 3 | 1   | Dans bio

boos_tb
id | name
-----------------
 1 | Maths
 2 | Science
 3 | English
 4 | French
 5 | Social Studies
```

I know I can select the users_tb and user_bio table by using JOIN statement, but my problem is how to add the book table to query when it does not relate to any of the previous tables.

The result i am expecting is like this

```
uid  | name |     bio     | bookid | bookname
------------------------------------------- 
 2   | Mick |  Micks bio  |    1   | Maths
 3   | Jane |  Janes bio  |    2   | Science
 1   | Dan  |  Dans bio   |    3   | English
null | null |    null     |    4   | French
null | null |    null     |    5   | Social Studies
```

I will be glad if anyone can be of help, thank you.

Comment: What results are you trying to get?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: In your case, how is Maths associated with Mick, Science with Jane, etc...?

Comment: they are not associated,  but I simply want to add the book table to query

Comment: In your result, you have Maths appearing in the same row as Mick. Something, somewhere has to decide why Maths should appear there vs in the row with Jane. You'll need to come up with the logic that makes that decision.